# Why does conda state that packages in my private conda repository on S3 are not available to install?

Tags: python, r, amazon-s3, anaconda, conda

I'm using S3 as a private conda repository and I am trying to install r-essentials through my custom S3 channel. I've uploaded all the tar.bz2 package archives for r-essentials into my S3 bucket. when I run a conda search I get the following results (which leads me to believe that conda can find the packages in my private conda repository on S3 conda):
[image: conda search]

Here are more packages:
[image: conda search 2]

However, when I run a conda install r-essentials, I get an error stating that the following packages are not available from the current channels:

[image: conda install]

Python is clearly available (based on the conda search results above), but the error lists Python as one of the packages that are not available...

After this long list, the current channels are outputted:

[image: current channels]

I've created my conda repository in the following format/structure on S3:

```
s3://<my-bucket>/pkgs/main/linux-64/repodata.json
s3://<my-bucket>/pkgs/main/linux-64/repodata.json.bz2
s3://<my-bucket>/pkgs/main/linux-64/<pkg1>.tar.bz2
s3://<my-bucket>/pkgs/main/linux-64/<pkg2>.tar.bz2
s3://<my-bucket>/pkgs/main/linux-64/<pkg3>.tar.bz2
...

These 2 files are required by default (even if there is no content in the noarch directory):
s3://<my-bucket>/pkgs/noarch/repodata.json
s3://<my-bucket>/pkgs/noarch/repodata.json.bz2
```

Has anyone experienced this issue before? Have I configured my private conda repository incorrectly? Why does conda search show my packages and conda install fail to find them?